Vue Plugin via CDN: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')" Error
I am building a Vue plugin that works fine when installed via npm but throws an error when imported dynamically via a CDN:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref') 
I suspect this issue arises because the plugin is using a different Vue instance than the host application.
Plugin Details

Vue version in host app: 3.5.13
Plugin build: Vite with vue externalized in vite.config.js:

      export default defineConfig({
          build: {
            lib: {
              entry: './src/index.js',
              name: 'NoteWriterPlugin',
              fileName: (format) => `noteWriter.${format}.js`,
              formats: ['es', 'umd'],
            },
            rollupOptions: {
              external: ['vue'],
              output: {
                globals: {
                  vue: 'Vue',
                },
              },
            },
          },
        });


Usage: I load the plugin dynamically like this:

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import loadPluginFromCDN from "./install.js";

const app = createApp(App);

const cdnUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/dist/noteWriter.umd.js";

(async () => {
  const plugin = await loadPluginFromCDN(cdnUrl);
  if (plugin && typeof plugin.install === "function") {
    app.use(plugin);
  } else {
    console.error("The plugin does not expose a valid 'install' method.");
  }

  app.mount("#app");
})();


export default async function loadPluginFromCDN(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = () => {
      // Ensure the global variable matches the name defined in your UMD build
      console.log(window.NoteWriterPlugin)
      resolve(window.NoteWriterPlugin);
    };
    script.onerror = () => {
      reject(new Error(`Failed to load script: ${url}`));
    };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}


Debugging Observations

The plugin exports an install function and appears to load correctly from the CDN:

  export default {
  install(app) {
    const count = ref(0); // Error occurs here
    app.provide("count", count);
  },
};



The error suggests that ref is undefined, indicating that the plugin and host app are using different Vue instances.

Steps Taken

I ensured vue is externalized in the plugin build (external: ['vue']).
Both the host app and the plugin are using Vue version 3.5.13 (checked via npm list vue).
When bundled via npm, the plugin works as expected, but loading via CDN results in the error.

Question
How can I ensure that my plugin shares the same Vue instance as the host app when loaded via a CDN? Is there a better way to handle this situation or pass the Vue instance to the plugin dynamically?

It's expected that ref is imported from vue, but this isn't shown. "I suspect this issue arises because the plugin is using a different Vue instance than the host application" - you need to debug bundled code. It's expected that it reads globalThis.Vue.ref and fails. If that's the case, make sure vue cdn is loaded prior to the moment it's used in the plugin
